# How can I set pdfinfo based on content of external file?

Tags: pdftex, xetex, hyperref, warnings, metadata

How can I include the contents of an external file in the PDF metadata (either built-in attribute like `Subject`, or custom one like `My ID`)?

I have written some text to `shell-output.txt` with, for example, `date > shell-output.txt` or `git rev-parse HEAD > shell-output.txt` (exact content doesn't matter). I am compiling with `xelatex demo.tex`, and I am open to additional flags like `--shell-escape` for `write18`.

- The PDF metadata *should* include the content of my file
- The PDF metadata does include the literal file name, not its content

Error from logs:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\@ifnextchar' on input line 10.
```

Example to produce:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
pdfinfo={
MyID={\input{shell-output.txt}},
% Custom PDF metadata not shown in many applications,
% switch to more common attribute for debug
% Subject={\input{shell-output.txt}},
}
}

\begin{document}
Unimportant.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input won't work here, but you can read the content of the file manually,
line by line, and assign that to variables and later use that, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

    \newread    \myFile
    \openin     \myFile = shell-output.txt
    
    \read       \myFile to \myOutputLineOne
    \read       \myFile to \myOutputLineTwo

    \hypersetup{%
        pdfinfo={%
            Subject =   {\myOutputLineOne},
            Author  =   {\myOutputLineTwo},
        }
    }

Lorem ipsum.

    \closein    \myFile
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is it that `input` won't work? From what I found online, people say it just reads a file and inputs it into the document as if it has been typed in.

Comment: It's got to to with the order in which commands are interpreted: `hyperref` expects a parameter at this point, but you're giving it a command LaTeX would have had to interpret before. As you've seen, this does not work. You'd have to ask a wizard for details.